# How to show CSV Excel list in an HTML website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, csv

I'm new to computer science, and I am tinkering with CSV files for the first time. I have a CSV file I created in Excel that looks like this:

```
[Name]   [Country]   [Bio]

[Amelia]   [America]   [etc. etc.]
[John]     [Germany]   [etc. etc.]
```

I want the lists to appear in my website per designated list, so it would look like:

```
 Name: Amelia
 Country: America
 Bio: Etc. etc.

 Name: John
 Country: Germany
 Bio: Etc. etc.
```

The formatting I can do with css, but how would I print my csv file into my website?

I also want to be able to add to my csv file from the website, though I have no idea where to start since my knowledge of javascript is very limited, but I want to create something like this:

```
Enter a name: (input)
Enter their country: (input)
Enter their Bio: (input)
```

And have it add to the list under its corresponding name.

The main problem is that I have no idea how to connect my website to my HTML file. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the language you are using? Java, .NET?

Comment: I'm using HTML/CSS for my website and I'm trying to use JavasScript to link the csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery has some tools for this. Import jquery dependency in your home html. [This](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/parsing-a-csv-file-with-javascript--cms-25626) link may help you.

Comment: That guide is going to be really helpful. Thank you so much! I am new to jquery but I will try my best.

Comment: Jquery they used for using AJAX to read the file. Rest everything is in plain JS. 
If the solution worked for you please accept the answer as correct one.